# Terraform clone repo directory and files to new VM instance

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, cloud-init

So I'm trying to clone a repo to my newly created linux vm instance using Terraform and cloud-init.

The newly created instance does not have access to the repo so I need to do this from terraform. I can happily clone the repo in terraform and then pick specific single files I want and copy those to the instance but I really want to just clone the repo across.
Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? please?

I have tried variations on the following (none of which I can get to work):

```
part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      rm -rf ~/tmp/myrepo
      git clone --depth=1 https://github/myrepo.git ~/tmp/myrepo
    EOF
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to clone a repo to my newly created linux vm instance using
> Terraform and cloud-init.

The prerequisites we required before cloning the process.

1. Having the access to Linux VM
2. Terraform installed in local machine
3. You should have SSH keys generated for accessing the VM

**Step 1**: Generate SSH keys

1. Open terminal or command prompt
2. Run the command to generate the SSH keys

```
      ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

3. Specify the key location and set a passphrase and note down the path which can be required later on.

**Step 2**: Create the test script

1. Create a new file `testscript.sh` and open in text editor.
2. Copy paste the contents into the `testscript.sh` file

**testscript.sh**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxx-new
```

3. Save the file

**Step 3:** Configure the Terraform script.

1. Create a new terraform file.
2. Add the following configuration to the file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "null_resource" "remote_script" {
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = "00.00.0.0"
    user        = "xyz"
    private_key = file("/home/mt/.ssh/id_rsa")
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo '${file("/home/mt/abc/testscript.sh")}' > /home/xyz/testscript.sh",  
      "chmod +x /home/xyz/testscript.sh",  # Make the script executable
      "/home/xyz/testscript.sh" 
    ]
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace the placeholders with appropriate values of VM.

**terraform apply**

[image]

If the execution is completed, the GIT repository specified in the testscript.sh file will be cloned to the VM as shown above.

**Step 4:** Verify the Cloned Repository

1. Once the terraform script executed, you can log in to the VM to verify the repository cloned.
2. Connect to the VM via SSH
3. Now list out the resources available in VM with the command.

Once connected and able to navigate the appropriate directory and list the files to confirm the repository was cloned successfully.

[image]